Density-Dependent Diffusion Dispersion Relation
I'm studying a model which incorporates the following PDE
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=uf(u)+D(1-\alpha f(u))\frac{d^{2}u}{dx^{2}}-D\alpha\frac{df(u)}{dx}\frac{du}{dx}$$
With zero flux boundary conditions n an out of equilibrium system where  I've taken $f(u_{0})=0$ and started by doing a linearization around an homogeneous stationary state '$u_0$', but it seems that doing so results in another model which has already been well studied, it's just the reaction-diffusion equation:
$$\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial t}=L[uf(u)]_{u_0}\mu+D\frac{d^{2}\mu}{dx^{2}}$$
Where I'm using $\mu=u-u_0$ to represent the perturbation and $L[uf(u)]_{u_0}$ is the linearization of the reaction terms around the steady state.
I would like to obtain a dispersion relation near the steady state which captures the behavior of the reaction dependent aspect of the diffusion given by $\alpha f(u)$, but I'm having trouble doing so and thought perhaps taking more terms in the taylor expansion would do the trick. Can someone help out with this?

The reason I'd like to get a dispersion relation is so that I can study the instability as we often do when analyzing Turing Patterns, in reality this PDE is part of a set of coupled nonlinear PDEs $u_{1},u_{2},...$ meant to model reactants interacting with each other, but I thought it might be simpler to just look at the dispersion relation for one of them first and then apply the same method to the rest of the system and extending $f(u)$ to $f_{j}(u_{1},u_{2},...)$ and considering $D_{j}$s and $\alpha_{j}$s, so I'm going one step at a time.

You could linearize near the steady state, but for that you need to find the steady state, which means solving for $u(x)$ when $\partial_t u(x,t)=0$. It is not necessarily homogeneous (if it exists at all.)

Your second equation assumes that $u_0$ is such that $f(u_0) = 0$, but an homogeneous steady state also exists around $u=0$ (as long as $f(0) $is not singular), in which case, you have some of the $\alpha$ dependence in your second term because $D\to D(1-\alpha f(0))$, no idea if it's physical tho.. What is it exactly that you are trying to obtain with the dispersion relation?

Hey guys! That's my bad, one of the core assumptions is that $f(u_{0})=0$, so its indeed a solution for the PDE and it is also considered to be homogeneous. I would like to obtain information about the instability of the system around the steady state. I'll update the question with more helpful info.

Then the homogeneous state is stable as long as $u_0f'(u_0)<0$ I guess (but I should do carefuly the linearization). Since you only have one field, you cannot obtain Turing pattern that typically arise when you have two species diffusing with vastly different diffusion coefficient. Also you should do @Syrocco in your comment if you want me yo have a notification of your message

Ah I didn't read your edit. Now I think I understand, you want to obtain Turing pattern using this u dependent coefficient of restitution when you have multiple field?  If $f$ is the same for every specie, then I guess you will not obtain any pattern because, as you say, close to the homogenous state the coefficient of diffusion of each specie is more or less the same. On top of that, to obtain Turing pattern you must somehow have an inhibitor and an activator, here if $f$ is the same for each field you will probably not have this kind of requirement fulfilled.

@Syrocco Yes, well, $f$ is not the same for every field, I'll index it properly, sorry. I've actually run a couple simulations with this model and have mostly focused on the evolution of the population for reactants in phase space, but I'm dissatisfied with doing a simulation without some mathematical backbone to stand beside it. All this is for my undergrad thesis and the ALL references I've checked are of little help for this particular problem.

So! Is your final equation: $$\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial t}=u_jf_j(u_1,u_2,...)+D_j(1-\alpha_j f_j(u_1,u_2,...))\frac{d^{2}u_j}{dx^{2}}-D_j\alpha\frac{df_j(u_1,u_2,...)}{dx}\frac{du_j}{dx}$$? If so, is the stability criterium giving you the homogenous solutions $\tilde u_i$: $f_j(\tilde u_1,\tilde u_2,...)=0$? for all $j$?

If it is the case, then, as you said, close to the homogenous state. The effective diffusion coefficient of each specie will be $D_j$ and you cannot count on the term in $\alpha_j$ to help destabilise your system because it is vanishingly small (and it makes sense physically, no need to go to second order). THEN! To see if you can obtain Turing pattern, you simply have to diagonalize the matrix (in k space) formed by your linearized system. Each eigenvalue will give you a "normal" model/dispersion relation. From which you can check stability

You can consider more generally:
$$
\partial_t u+f(u)+\partial_x(D(u)\partial_xu)) = 0
$$
with $D$ a function of $u$. If you are interested in the linear stability of a homogeneous solution $u_0$ such that $f(u_0)=0$, then you just need to linearise the equation $u = u_0+v$:
$$
\partial_t v+v\cdot\partial_uf(u_0)+D(u_0)\partial_x^2v = 0
$$
or with index notation:
$$
\partial_t v_i+v_j\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial u_j}(u_0)+D_{kl}(u_0)\frac{\partial^2v_i}{\partial x_k\partial x_l} = 0
$$
In particular, your "dispersion" relation will be assuming the spatio-temporal dependence:
$$
v=\hat v e^{st+ik\cdot x} \\
(sI+\partial_uf(u_0)-D(u_0)k\otimes k)\hat v = 0
$$
in other words, you need to solve the characteristic polynomial of $-\partial_uf(u_0)+D(u_0)k\otimes k$:
$$
\det(sI+\partial_uf(u_0)-D(u_0)k\otimes k) = 0
$$
